# Laravel Export: Attempt to read property "second_key" on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-excel

I need to export data with Laravel Export, but the code return ErrorException: Attempt to read property `"second_key"` on `null`.

My code:

```PHP
<?php
namespace App\Admin\Extensions;
use Encore\Admin\Grid\Exporters\ExcelExporter;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
class DataExporter extends ExcelExporter implements FromQuery, WithMapping, ShouldAutoSize
{
protected $fileName = 'Export Data.xlsx';
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'ID',
            'Title',
            'Status',
            'Gender',
            'Data',
        ];
    }
    public function map($data): array
    {
        return [
            $data->id,
            $data->title,
            $data->status,
            $data->gender,
            $data->json_data->second_key, // <-- Here's the error
        ];
    }

}
```

I've tried to check using this:

`print_r(json_encode($data->json_data));`

and this is the result:

```json
{
      "id": 282,
      "second_key": "second_value",
      "third_key": "6200",
      "fourth_key": "0000",
      "fifth_key": 28
}
```

I've also done this:

```PHP
return [
     $data->id,
     $data->title,
     $data->status,
     $data->gender,
     $data->json_data //Without "second_key"
];
```

and the excel cell returns the same result:

```json
{
      "id": 282,
      "second_key": "second_value",
      "third_key": "6200",
      "fourth_key": "0000",
      "fifth_key": 28
}
```

Comment: Could you `print_r($data->json_data);` without `json_encode`? What type is `$data->json_data`? How many rows does this file have and are you sure those values are present in all rows? It would be easier to just exit on `if(is_null($data->json_data)) dd($data);` before the `return [` line and set the last line in the returned array `$data->json_data->second_key` to an empty string `'"` to verify which row might causing the trouble.

Comment: it's Object. I have almost 6k rows. And you're right, I just remember when you asked. I have to handle if there are some empty rows. lol. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Oh only 6k? Thought there would be more :D

Comment: Yup xD I've solved the problem myself, and it worked! thanks for making me remember it, lol xD Should I delete this question? or.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@dbf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1653305/dbf) said in the comment section, I have to handle empty rows. I have checked several times in the database, and maybe I missed that one blank row.
Anyway, this is how I handle those values:

```php
if (!isset($data->json_data->second_key)) {
    $second_key = '-';
} else {
    $second_key = $data->json_data->second_key;
}

return [
     $data->id,
     $data->title,
     $data->status,
     $data->gender,
     $second_key
];
```